# How to create tabs for JQuery terminal

Tags: html, jquery, css, tabs, jquery-terminal

Im trying to create a tab system for my JQuery terminal, but I cant see how I can add functionality to it.
For example, I want the X button to close the current tab, and a + button to open a new tab.
Im not really good a javascript obviously, but how can I get started in getting this to work?
I have seen an example from github that could help me, but I cant access it right now since my school blocks sites, so if you are reading this, can you get the code from here: https://gist.github.com/lawrenceamer/3f2d48be524ee0eca95ada3910d4294d and put it in stack overflow for me? Or give me tips in completing this?

This is the code I have made so far:

```html
<link href="https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/1db29588408eadbd4406aae9238555eb?family=Consolas" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="thetabs.css" rel='stylesheet'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/menlo');
</style>

<style>
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
a {
font-family: Menlo;
}
.ui-tabs .ui-state-active:after {
  content: "x";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tab {
  outline: none;
}
  #terminal-tabs {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  #terminal-tabs ul {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  body {
  zoom: reset !important;
}
  #tab-1,
  #tab-2,
  #tab-3 {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  #tab-1 iframe,
  #tab-2 iframe,
  #tab-3 iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
</style>

<div id="terminal-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">My-Terminal   (1)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">My-Terminal   (2)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">My-Terminal   (3)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">My-Terminal   (4)</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1">

     <!-- terminal is hosted here from iframe  -->
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">

       <!-- terminal is hosted here from iframe  -->
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">

 <!-- terminal is hosted here from iframe  -->
  </div>
    <div id="tab-4">

    <!-- terminal is hosted here from iframe  -->
  </div>
</div>



<script>

$(function() {
  $("#terminal-tabs").tabs();
});

$("#terminal-tabs").on("click", ".ui-tabs-close", function() {
  var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
  $("#" + panelId).remove();
  $("#terminal-tabs").tabs("refresh");
});
$("#terminal-tabs .ui-tabs-nav").append('<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-new"><a href="#">+</a></li>');

$("#terminal-tabs").on("click", ".ui-tabs-new", function() {
  var newTabIndex = $("#terminal-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li").length - 1;
  $("#terminal-tabs").tabs("add", "#tab-" + newTabIndex, "Tab " + newTabIndex);
});
</script>
```

(Note: I also understand that stackoverflow is not just a site where you could ask anything and expect an answer back, but I mostly do coding on a school pc since I dont have a working pc right now, and so I try to work with what I have. And yes, I have tried to do some research on this because google exists, but with my school's blocking system, there are alot of limitations.)

Comment: Here is an example of [jQuery Terminal Tabs](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/mdBjdvq) I hope you can open CodePen.

Comment: Also if you just want the tabs and terminal inside the HTML you can just Google jQuery Tabs, there are plenty of examples (also you can search on SO) of how to create tabs with jQuery. You don't need anything specific to jQuery Terminal (I think).

Comment: @jcubic thanks, but CodePen is also blocked for me ``/
I did come accross some examples that could help me and I was able to come up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/xxlolcoolsofunxx/7aqvs0we/ 
It sorta works, but has bugs, and if you try it out, you will see what i mean. How can I perfect my code there? Im getting real close but its kinda difficult to find examples without the code being for extensions, or blocked.

Comment: I can copy my CodePen code as a stack snippet. Sorry, I don't like time fixing your code.

Comment: @jcubic ayo thanks jcubic c: just one last question, how can I get your code to be my interpreter?
What i mean is that the tabs has stuff like greetings creating its own terminal, so how can I put in my own based on your article: https://itnext.io/how-to-create-interactive-terminal-like-website-888bb0972288

Comment: I think that I didn't expose the interpreter in my code. Will update my example. PS: you should ask about my example, not about your question.

Comment: Update the asnwer, also change `init` to `terminal_tabs` so it has the same API as the library, added options.label for the Tab label, and removed all the `vars` since it was not in fact ES5 it only had var instead of const/let.

Comment: @jcubic Alr, thanks man. And sorry if this is a stupid question, but do you mean to change my question to ask for your example? And just another quick question, I have a command that changes the cursor color using the .cmd class, and it works, but doesnt change it across all tabs. I feel like it has to be with the tab's css but I have other command that changes text color and bg color and it works on all tabs, so im not sure why its not working here. But thanks for your help

Comment: About your first question, if you ask a question about my code write in it my answer below, not on your question if it's not related to the question but to my answer. And about the second thing. I suggest to ask another question.

Comment: @jcubic Alr mb, and ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let count = 0;
terminal_tabs({
    echo(...args) {
       this.echo(args);
    }
}, {
    checkArity: false,
    greetings: 'This is really working'
});

function terminal_tabs(interpreter, option) {
    new_terminal(interpreter, option);
    $('.cloak').removeClass('cloak');

    $('.tabs').on('click', 'li.tab', function() {
        var li = $(this);
        tab_activate(this);
        return false;
    }).on('click', 'li.tab .close', function() {
        remove_tab(this);
        return false;
    }).on('click', 'li.new', () => new_terminal(interpreter, option));
    
}

function remove_tab(el) {
    el = $(el);
    const $li = el.closest('li');
    const $tabs = el.closest('.tabs');
    const index = $li.index();
    const $terminals = $tabs.find('.content > div');
    const $term = $terminals.eq(index).terminal();
    if ($terminals.length > 1 && $term.is('.active')) {
        const $other = $term.prev();
        if (!$other.length) {
            $other = $term.next();
        }
        const $new_li = $tabs.find('> ul li').eq($other.index());
        tab_activate($new_li);
    }
    $term.destroy().remove();
    $li.remove();
}

function tab_activate(li) {
    const $li = $(li);
    const index = $li.index();
    $li.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    const $content = $li.closest('ul').next();
    const $tab = $content.children()
         .eq(index)
         .addClass('active');
    $tab.siblings()
        .removeClass('active');
}


function new_terminal(interpreter = $.noop, options = null, label = null) {
    const id = ++count;
    options = options ?? {
        greetings: `Welcome to jQuery Terminal, no: ${id}.\n`
    };
    const $term = $('<div/>').terminal(interpreter, options);
    label = options.label ?? `Terminal &lt;${id}&gt;`;
    const $li = $(`<li class="tab">
                   <a href="#">${label}</a>
                   <span class="close">&times</span>
                 </li>`);
    const $content = $('.tabs .content');
    if ($content.is(':empty')) {
        $li.add($term).addClass('active');
    }
    const $add = $('.tabs > ul li.new');
    $li.insertBefore($add);
    $content.append($term);
    tab_activate($li);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: black;
}
:root {
    --size: 1.4;
    --color: #18B70A;
    --glow: 1;
}
.tabs.cloak {
    display: none;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
/* tabs */
.tabs {
    --gap: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    --original-background: var(--backgroud, #000);
}
.tabs, .tabs .content > div {
    height: 100%;
}
.tabs > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: var(--gap, 10px) var(--gap, 10px) 0;
    font-family: var(--font, monospace);

}
.tabs > ul > li {
    border-color: var(--color, #aaa);
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 14px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: calc(var(--size, 1) * 12px);
}
.tabs > ul > li > * {
    background: var(--background, #000);
    color: var(--color, #aaa);
    text-shadow: 0 0 calc(var(--glow) * 5px) var(--color, #ccc);
}
.tabs > ul > li .close, .tabs > ul > li.new a {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0.9em;
    padding: 0 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.tabs > ul > li .close:hover, .tabs > ul > li.new a:hover {
    --background: var(--link-color, #3377FF);
    --color: var(--original-background, #000);
}
.tabs > ul > li + li {
    margin-left: var(--gap, 10px);
}
.tabs > ul > li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tabs > ul > li.active::after {
    background-color: var(--background, #000);
    bottom: -1px;
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.tabs .content {
    border-top: solid 1px var(--color, #ccc);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.tabs .content > :not(.active) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="tabs cloak">
    <ul>
        <li class="new">
            <a href="#">+</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```